# symfony add LoggerInterface to already started project

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

i need to add LoggerInterface, to an already stated project, i implemented in a api platform operation

here it's an example:

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *     name="post_users",
     *     path="/customers",
     *     methods={"POST"},
     *     defaults={
     *         "_api_item_operation_name"="_post_users"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function __invoke(Users $data, LoggerInterface $logger): JsonResponse{
        $content = $this->request->getContent();
        $logger->info('['.$this->request->getMethod().'] saveUser', [$content]);
        $response = $this->usersController->saveUser($data);
        $logger->info('[RESPONSE] saveUser:', [$response->getContent()]);
        return $response;
    }
```

but the log doesn't show (in /var/log), the thing that i need most is the step by step to activate the LoggerInterface if it's possible

Comment: You have a logger service defined otherwise you would have a big error message.  By default, logs are written to the var/log directory so check there.  You can then adjust the location via the monolog.yaml files by following the docs.

Comment: Please share more details - did you only add such an interface or any logger service like Monolog?

Comment: Read the [monolog documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) adapt your configuration and please provide your `config/packages/monolog.yaml` file in the question please